# Why aren't all 100% of the DIV is used?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="dispLoginSearch"> <!-- LOGIN AND SEARCH -->
    <div class="loginBox">
        <p>Log in to <span>My</span> <span>M</span> | Sign Up</p>
        <div style="width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0; overflow: hidden; height: 38px;" class="brClear">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Username" id="txtUsername" class="txtUsername styledTB floatLeft" />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="pwPassword" class="txtPassword styledTB floatLeft" />
            <a href="JavaScript:void(0);" class="styledBtn logBtn floatLeft">Login</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#">Forgot login/password</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.dispLoginSearch
{
    width: 40%;
    height: 180px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 3%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.loginBox {
    margin-top: 3%;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font: 16px sans-serif;
    padding: 0 0 0 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
.loginBox p {
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.txtUsername{
    width: 38%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 30px;
}
.txtPassword {
    width: 38%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    height: 30px;
}
.floatLeft
{
    float: left;
}
.logBtn
{
    width: 10%;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.styledBtn
{
    background: #d75813;
    display: block;
    box-shadow:
        0px 5px #BC490A,
        0px 8px 10px rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.5);
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.styledTB {
    padding-left: 5px;
    background: #E8E8E8;
    opacity: 1;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    right: 35px;
    box-shadow:
        0px 5px #BBB,
        0px 8px 10px rgba(148, 148, 148, 0.5);
}
```

If I keep the `logBtn` at 10% it stays in the same line but the letter gets cut off almost:

[image]

If I increase the percentage to 12%, instead of expanding on the same line to fill up the DIV, it goes to the next line:

[image]

For some reason I am not able to use the 100% of the width from the parent DIV. I used `float: right` on the forgot login/password link and that's how far it goes. For some reason the right side of the DIV is completely not accessible.

How do I resolve the issue?

The inline style will be removed when I have resolved the issue.

Comment: Accidentally added it. Removed it. thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/90Lz6c3n/ not cutting  login btn

Comment: Looks good, what did you modify? :)

Comment: Looks good to me too. what browser are you seeing this on?

Comment: IE10, let me test it out on Chrome :/

Comment: Chrome is doing the same exact thing

Comment: Updated my question to reflect why I am having an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the horizontal paddings you are adding onto the inputs. Those are added to the percentage width and percentage margin you have put on the inputs.

try using the `box-sizing: border-box;` property on the inputs so the paddings won't get added to the specified width and margins

Some explaination about box-sizing can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: BTW, to use the 100% of you width, your input button should be 20% width, not 12%

Comment: the `dispLoginSearch` is what is causing the issue. It is setting a 3% margin-right which overlaps the `loginBox`

Comment: The 3% padding-right has no effect on the inputs and the submit button themselves since they are not the direct children of `dispLoginSearch`. The width of `brClear` is calculated and that's what the inputs and submit button are using to in turn calculate theirs. The fact that paddings aren't taken into account when calculating a blocks width (in the default behaviour, modified by `box-sizing`) is what's throwing everything off cause now the inputs' outer widths are 38% + 2% + 5px (from the `.styleTB` rule) and not the "clean" 38% + 2%.

Comment: Also the only reason the `dispLoginSearch` and the `loginBox` are overlapping is that the `loginBox` has a 100% width AND borders AND a left padding. (which is also solved using the `box-sizing: border-box;` property.
I'm telling you, this property is like magic and should be used much more.

Comment: The culprit was another section of the code for the `loginBox a` which had a `margin-right: 30px` and now that I removed it everything is working out fine!!! Phew! Thanks for the help :)